# A simple PNG wrapper that works. Anybody have a snippet to share?

Tags: c++, c, image, png

I'm looking for a way to get a buffer of image data into a PNG file, and a way to get a PNG file into a buffer.

There are just these two things I want to do.

It would be a dead simple wrapper that uses `png.h`. Well, not exactly dead simple because of the horribly complex libpng API, but the concept of it is.

I tried DevIL before. It is much easier to use than libpng. Still, I have had [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7379058/devil-segfault-issues-with-pngs-bmps) with it. Also, DevIL does *too much*. I only need lean and mean basic PNG format support, not 20 other formats as well.

Then I find [this page](http://zarb.org/~gc/html/libpng.html). I praised the Pixel Fairy and the Almighty Google for giving me an implementation on a silver platter... Then it turns out this screws up the image: in the processed image every fourth pixel in each scanline goes missing. I am fairly certain from reading the source that this is not meant to happen! It's supposed to zero out red and set green to blue. That didn't happen either.

I have also tried png++. The issue I had with it is that I couldn't get data out of a PNG in a format compatible for loading into OpenGL, I would have to construct another buffer. It just looked ugly, but I will definitely try png++ again before I even think about giving DevIL another shot. Because png++ worked, at least. It's also got the header-only aspect going for it. Still, it did produce a bunch of compiler warnings.

Are there any other contenders? Anybody who has worked with directly using libpng would know how to make what I am asking for: one function that takes a filename and fills a 32-bpp buffer and sets two resolution integers; one function that takes a 32-bpp buffer, two resolution integers, and a filename.

Update-edit: I found [this](http://lodev.org/lodepng/). Might be something there.

Comment: Yes, lodePNG is probably what you want

Comment: I'm not so sure now. It's not depending on libpng and so it doesn't seem to use it. What's with all these people implementing image representation formats by themselves? Programming exercise?

Comment: libpng is not that hard to use directly, while lodePNG is a self-contained single-file png parser with many limitations and poor speed compared to libpng. Choose according to your requirements.

Comment: I just find it frustrating that libpng isn't so easy to use and wrappers for it like png++ don't really make it much easier... Yes it's nice you have all these things you can do, but how about some utility functions, eh?

Answer (score 2):

This [tutorial](http://www.piko3d.com/tutorials/libpng-tutorial-loading-png-files-from-streams) seems to have what you want.

From the link:

```
 //Here's one of the pointers we've defined in the error handler section:
    //Array of row pointers. One for every row.
    rowPtrs = new png_bytep[imgHeight];

    //Alocate a buffer with enough space.
    //(Don't use the stack, these blocks get big easilly)
    //This pointer was also defined in the error handling section, so we can clean it up on error.
    data = new char[imgWidth * imgHeight * bitdepth * channels / 8];
    //This is the length in bytes, of one row.
    const unsigned int stride = imgWidth * bitdepth * channels / 8;

    //A little for-loop here to set all the row pointers to the starting
    //Adresses for every row in the buffer

    for (size_t i = 0; i < imgHeight; i++) {
        //Set the pointer to the data pointer + i times the row stride.
        //Notice that the row order is reversed with q.
        //This is how at least OpenGL expects it,
        //and how many other image loaders present the data.
        png_uint_32 q = (imgHeight- i - 1) * stride;
        rowPtrs[i] = (png_bytep)data + q;
    }

    //And here it is! The actuall reading of the image!
    //Read the imagedata and write it to the adresses pointed to
    //by rowptrs (in other words: our image databuffer)
    png_read_image(pngPtr, rowPtrs);
```

Comment: This may help me understand it well enough to find out what the zarb.org sample code messed up. Thanks.

Comment: I heartily suggest using some vectors here.

Comment: Steven, were you able to fix the zarg.org sample code? I'm in the same place that you were in and would like a one stop function for reading in a png and getting the rgba data out to OpenGL.

Comment: FWIW I generally use PPM binary fed through a raw zlib stream, I call it the ppmz format. Much less of a headache than PNG...

Answer (score 2):

I'd add CImg to the list of options. While it is an image library the API is not so high level as most (devil/imagemagick/freeimage/GIL). It is also header only.

The image class has simple width height and data members with public access. Under the hood it uses libpng (if you tell it to with preprocessor directive).  The data is cast to whatever type you chose for the templated image object.

```
CImg<uint8_t>myRGBA("fname.png");
myRGBA._data[0] = 255; //set red value of first pixel
```

Comment: Nice, This is a header-only library weighing in at 112K. Taking a peek around inside, they get down and dirty... Written by a researcher who clearly knows what he's doing. Sure to be a time-saver and seems to have a lot of interesting low level features including such things as built-in fonts and other fancy stuff. Now it might be just a bit too much extra for "wrapper for libPNG" but it does fit the bill...

Comment: It is pretty c-style c++ though. I thought about refactoring some parts but it has so many macros. Lacking comments too.

Comment: yeah an abundance of macros can be either an abomination or just awesome. i'll need to poke at it some before i can conclude anything. But i wont be back to working on image processing code for a while

Answer (score 1):

[Sean Barrett](http://www.nothings.org/) has written two public-domain files for PNG image [reading](http://www.nothings.org/stb_image.c)/[writing](http://www.nothings.org/stb_image_write.h).